# How to return JSON response in below format from MySQL table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, phpmyadmin

In my Database table I store dates in a format like this **2015-03-22** in a date column.

```
|   mydate   |
------------
| 2015-03-22 |
| 2015-03-17 |
| 2015-04-02 |
| 2015-04-01 |
```

I need `JSON` to return a response like:

```
    {  
   "result": [{    
     "2014":[{}],
     "2015":[{
        "April":[
            "2015-04-05",
            "2015-04-04",
            "2015-04-03",
            "2015-04-01"
        ],
        "March":[
            "2015-03-25",
            "2015-03-14",
            "2015-03-07",
            "2015-03-01"
        ]
     }] 
   }]    
}
```

I tried this query, but I failed to make JSON objects like above:

```
$getDate = "SELECT DISTINCT( mydate), MONTHNAME( mydate ) AS m, YEAR( mydate ) as y 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY m, mydate  ORDER BY mydate DESC";
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it? I mean whats your problem?

Comment: unable to get json response in above format. Can't understand how to arrange year, months and date in that manner.

Comment: so actually you are using some json_encode sort of function i think?

Comment: Please post your code with some sample data and lets fix it now.

Comment: Encoding it to json is trivial. You need to collect your database response into a datastructure.

Comment: i pasted above query. And trying to arrange data but cant get proper result.

Comment: Whats your table structure? and sample data? You should post it as we will try your query to fix you with it.

Comment: @Testing. yes,  i want to make json response using json_encode. But i can not made array in proper format

Comment: @SHAZ Yeah, I understands. So please post that complete code as well.

Comment: I swear I didn't down voted mate. As you didn't post your code comptely and just needed ready made code so some other downvoted you as its against the rules of SO.

Comment: We don't have many rules here, @Testing, but we have quite a few guidelines. People can up/downvote for any reason they wish, but my guess would be that either the "ASAP" in the title was thought rather cheeky (people will rightly answer at their leisure) and there was no evidence of prior attempt. Readers here will often encourage posters to show what they've tried, and as you say, requests for "ready made code" sometimes are not well received.

Comment: @halfer Well, Thanks for your time explaining me but SO is not for providing ready made code and mostly member discourage it as its against the ethics of programming and coding. First try, keep test, keep clean, keep code, keep fix and you have you final output. If not then you should follow SO with your code and all relevant things but question should be proper and well delivered. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sequentially define a nested array:

```
$sql = "SELECT
    DISTINCT( mydate) AS `date`,
    MONTHNAME( mydate ) AS m,
    YEAR( mydate ) as y
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    m, mydate
ORDER BY
    mydate DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($c, $sql);

$structure = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    //year
    if(!isset($structure[$row['y']]))
    {
        $structure[$row['y']] = array();
    }

    //month inside the year
    if(!isset($structure[$row['y']][$row['m']]))
    {
        $structure[$row['y']][$row['m']] = array();
    }

    //date inside the month
    $structure[$row['y']][$row['m']][] = $row['date'];
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

//encode to json
$structure = array('result' => $structure);
$json = json_encode($structure);
```

Comment: Perfect code. great way of writing. must be best practice. :) How did you code it so nicely? :)

Comment: Really i tried more than 3hrs but now i am happy. :)

Comment: @Testing I had similar tasks during work, and quickly understood, how to solve the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @user4035 well perfectly coded this that time and indeed the great programming approaches.:) so how to be a great and good programmer who can easily code these things? ;) any tip and proper guidence?

Comment: @Testing I can recommend SICP - it's an old course (1985), but if you watch the lectures and solve the problems from the book - it would be very helpful.

Comment: @user4035 Thank you very much Sir. I will definitely read this course and watch the lectures. thanks. ;)